# Can the Segment Analytics .NET library on localhost not send data to the cloud?

Tags: .net, segment-analytics

I'm trying to use the Segment Analytics .NET library in an application. Is there a way to configure it so that it doesn't actually send data to the cloud? Like a "NoOp" when it comes to the actual sending of data?

[The documentation states the following](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/server/net/#development-settings) (for development purposes):

> You can use this initialization during development while testing the library. `SetAsync(false)` will make sure the library makes a request to our servers every time it’s called.
>
> `Analytics.Initialize("YOUR_WRITE_KEY", new Config().SetAsync(false));`
> Don’t forget to set async back to true for production, so that you can advantage of asynchronous flushing on a different thread.

To me, this reads as: "On localhost development, you will STILL SEND THE DATA to the cloud -but- instead of trying to be efficient and batching it up, etc... we'll send it ASAP after each call."

Which sucks because I would like the option to NOT send any data anywhere, but my code 'thinks' it's getting sent, still.

Is there a special configuration trick?

Answer (score 0):

There's a (not documented?) property called `Send` .. which will either send the data upstream or not (a nop using a `FakeRequestHandler`).

e.g.

```
Analytics.Initialize("YOUR_WRITE_KEY", new Config{ Send = false });
```

Here's [the code in their library that does all this](https://github.com/segmentio/Analytics.NET/blob/452a4e060db3ebaf435be198895e022c9efa2b41/Analytics/Client.cs#L64-L79).